# Driving on suspended license

Tags: traffic

I got a ticket for driving on suspended license. I appeared for arraignment but the court did not have any record of it. How long does the officer have to file that ticket in the state of Michigan.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the deadline, at a minimum, the officer certainly has to file that ticket before the arraignment date on the ticket that is served upon you.

This said, you could be served with a reissued ticket with a new arraignment date in the future, and as long as that reissued ticket was filed in a timely fashion and was served and filed within the statute of limitations for the offense, the charge would not be dismissed with prejudice.